# Tailwind CSS @apply not working with pseudo classes

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am trying to create reusable classes for things such as buttons or inputs.

I have a global.css file with this code

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
    .btn {
        @apply border border-pri hover: border-pri bg-pri rounded-lg py-2 px-4 font-semibold uppercase text-white hover: bg-sec transition duration-200 ease-in-out;
    }
}

:root {
    --primary: 88 28 135;
    --secondary: 147 51 234;
    --tertiary: 243 232 255;
}
```

If you look at the hover class, for some reason vscode keeps giving a space after writing a pseudo class or breakpoint such as hover or sm. I thought it was prettier but the issue still persists after doing the /* prettier-ignore */ comment. I am not sure what is causing this.

Even in the tailwind documents its shows that it is possible to add pseudo classes and breakpoints which is why I think it's vscode.

Has anyone else run into this? If it matters this is in a Next.js project.

Comment: I would try and disable all my extensions one by one to test which one is responsible for it.

Comment: I did that and even disabled all extensions but it was still happening. It must be a vscode setting. I have no clue where to even begin looking.

Comment: Check those solutions: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6284 This one looks promising: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6284#discussioncomment-2724521 Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing the settings below work!

(File > Preferences > Settings) under Text Editor > Files. Enter *.css for the item, and tailwindcss for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those having the same issue this forum helped. Thank you ChenBr!

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6284

Go to settings (File > Preferences > Settings).
Under Text Editor > Files.
Click Add Item.
Enter *.css for the item, and tailwindcss for the value